# What is the corresponding MySQL TimeStamp in MS SQL Server?

Tags: mysql

I need a timestamp to be created automatically when I insert information in a table. mySQL has TimeStamp but  MS SQL Server TimeStamp doesn’t correspond mySQL. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28SQL.80%29.aspx): "The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is not the same as the timestamp data type defined in the SQL-92 standard. The SQL-92 timestamp data type is equivalent to the Transact-SQL datetime data type."

To be able to have a date automatically inserted in your table, you should have a column of type datetime with a default value of getdate() - the system function that shows the current date of the system.

Comment: To build on that, if you are using SQL Server 2008 or higher you'll want to use the new SYSDATETIME() function or the SYSUTCDATETIME() function (if you want the UTC time).